# MoPub: Handle volatile device orientation and interstitials?

Tags: ads, interstitial, mopub

MoPub requires you to pick the orientation associated with an interstitial ad unit. How does that work with an app that allows rotation? The user may rotate the device in between fetching an interstitial and displaying it.

Other networks I've used in the past will just load a generic interstitial, and then display it at whatever orientation the device happens to be in when the time comes.

Is there a better way to handle this in MoPub, other than the obvious "Load two interstitials"? I'd rather not have the potential of loading two at a time for networks that don't require you to pick an orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Because MoPub has an orientation associated with and interstitial ad unit, I would set the orientation of the view immediately after the ad loads and then allow the orientation of the view to rotate on the close of the interstitial.

In Android, the method the MoPub SDK calls when an ad loads is:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
>     if (interstitial.isReady()) {
>         mInterstitial.show();
>     } else {
>         // Other code
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Before the ad is shown here, you can set the orientation of the device.

When the interstitial is closed, you can allow the orientation of the view to rotate.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {}
> ```

This way, you are loading only one interstitial and the interstitial will not be interrupted on rotation.